# Why Three js shadow not smooth?

Tags: three.js

I set shadow for directional light with shadow map size 2048, shadow bias -0.0001 and shadow type is PCSoftshadow, but rendered shadow seem look like low quality, not smooth and not correct (image below).

[image]

How I can make shadow smoother ?
This is my code for render shadow

```
    const dirLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 0.75);
    dirLight.color.setHSL(0.1, 1, 0.95);
    dirLight.position.set(-1, 1.75, 1);
    dirLight.position.multiplyScalar(30);
    this.scene.add(dirLight);

    dirLight.castShadow = true;
    dirLight.shadow.mapSize.width = 2048;
    dirLight.shadow.mapSize.height = 2048;

    const d = 80;
    dirLight.shadow.camera.left = -d;
    dirLight.shadow.camera.right = d;
    dirLight.shadow.camera.top = d;
    dirLight.shadow.camera.bottom = -d;
    dirLight.shadow.camera.far = 1000;
    dirLight.shadow.bias = -0.0001;
```